# Text in math: write from left to right instead of from center (KaTex)

Tags: math-mode

In math mode I want to include some text. I can use `\text{}`. But the problem is that the text is not written from left to right but from center. What could I use instead of `\text{}`?

Kind regards

Comment: I think that KaTeX like MathJaX is off-topic here. If I wrong...excuse me.

Comment: Can you show us some code, so that we can understand your problem better?

Comment: Please provide MWE even if it produces the undesired results that you would like to change.

Comment: Have you tried \hbox{...}, \mbox{...} or \makebox{...}?